# What happens if your element doesn't match the Colosseum's type?

Tags: dragonvale

I am trying to figure out how type affects the outcomes of the Colosseum. I always try to enter a dragon of the type that is asked for for the event but this time around they wanted a Metal dragon and I do not have one of those yet (I am too low of a level). So this has raised the question of how your type affects the outcome of the Colosseum.

As far as I can see you can send a single element dragon of the same type, an off type or an opposing type. Alternately you could send a hybrid dragon that could contain the type and off types or conflicting types or no matching types and just off or conflicting types.

Does the dragon choice really have any impact on this? Is this just random like breeding (not including rare dragons) as to what the outcome will be or can some thought be put into this to alter the outcome?

Comment: [I dunno lol](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/61357/11920). I'll make sure my next match up is the opposite element and see what happens

Comment: I currently have an air dragon competing in a metal event. So we shall see what happens.

Comment: Possible partial duplicate to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/61278/what-can-i-do-to-increase-my-chances-in-the-colosseum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are more likely to get higher scores if your element *matches* rather than opposes the arena's element. I put a plant in fire and got bronze, plant in plant and got gold. I believe that is the only difference.

I looked it up before too because I had a similar question. I did not find much on this actually, so I tested it myself and that outcome was always mis-match = bronze or silver match = silver or gold. (I unfortunately decided to test this after all my dragons were level 7, not 10 yet but all were at least 7 so many came out silver either way).

Comment: I put an Air in Metal and got absolutely Nothing.

Comment: @James I've now twice had the Metal Colosseum glitch out with no reward or announcement whatsoever.  The first time was with a high, probably level 10, Lightning Dragon.  The second time was with a level 10 Iron Dragon, so clearly you can get the Metal Colosseum glitch even when using metal dragons.

Answer (score 0):

The general rules are:

1. The higher the dragon's level, the better.
2. Hybrids are better than 'pure' dragons.
3. Choose the hybrid that has the competition event first.
4. If there are several dragon options, choose the one with higher value.

Based on this, I propose the following:

```
Plant       Pollen
Earth       Scoria
Water       Fog
Fire        Paper
Lightning   Magnetic
Metal       Copper
Air         Blazing
Cold        Snow
```

Comment: A very interesting answer @Joe - do you have any sources?